# Store doesn't cache nested objects

Tags: jsdata

v3.rc5
js-data-http rc.2

- my API responds with a nested resource e.g `/user` responds with a nested profile.
- "profile" and "user" are two mappers with respective relations

`"user":
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Peter",
  "profile": {
      "id": 5
      "dob": "today"
  }
}`

"profile" doesn't get added to the cache. I can call user.profile, but `store.cachedFind('profile', 5)` returns undefined.

calling manually 
`store.addToCache('profile', user.profile)`
would not throw any errors but also wouldn't add it to the cache.

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example (the key is defining the relationship between `user` and `profile`):

```
import { DataStore } from 'js-data';

const store = new DataStore();

store.defineMapper('user', {
  relations: {
    hasOne: {
      profile: {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        localField: 'profile'
      }
    }
  }
});

store.defineMapper('profile', {
  relations: {
    belongsTo: {
      user: {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        localField: 'user'
      }
    }
  }
});

const user = store.add('user', {
  id: 123,
  profile: {
    id: 345,
    userId: 123
  }
});

console.log(store.get('user', 123));
console.log(store.get('profile', 345));
console.log(user.profile === store.get('profile', 345));
```